# I have created profiles in Forge, how to import them to HAPI FHIR server?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have created an HL7 FHIR profile in Firely Forge. Let's call it MyPatient.structureDefinition.json

I'm able to send this profile as REST call to public FHIR server, but I can't find out how to import this profile to my own HAPI FHIR server that I'm implementing. I want my FHIR server to know my profile, so that I can validate resources against it.

HAPI's documentation about profiles does not explain this. https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/model/profiles_and_extensions.html

Have I misunderstood that I need to import profiles to FHIR server, or do I actually need to also create an implementation guide and somehow import it to HAPI FHIR server?

Comment: Have you tried just posting to the StructureDefinition endpoint on the server?

Comment: Yes I have tried to post it via REST. It gave error. Anyway this is not the way I want to do it, becauce I want FHIR server permanently to know my profiles. 

I have been reading more discussion groups and dokumenation and I think the problem might be because I'm running HAPI Plain server, not JPA?
HAPI dokumentation does not explain, how to use profiles in HAPI Plain server  mode. 

Is it so that you can't post via REST or import profiles to HAPI Plain server? You need to write profiles (resources) in code totally from scratch?